# Spring Data JPA - Native query on crud repositories works with joins?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an interface that extends CrudRepository and implements a method with **@Query** annotation with the attribute **nativeQuery** setted to true. This method returns a list of an entity.

Example:

```
public interface MessageTemplateRepository extends CrudRepository<MessageTemplate, Integer> {
  @Query(nativeQuery = true, "select template.* from plan_granted_template granted join license license on granted.fk_plan = license.fk_plan join message_template template on granted.fk_message_template = template.id where license.fk_garage = ?2 and template.message_type = ?1")
  public List<MessageTemplate> findGrantedTemplatesByMessageTypeAndGarage(MessageType messageType, Garage garage);
}
```

**The Garage has one License

The License has one Plan and Garage

The Plan has many MessageTemplate**

The class License has a ManyToOne relation with Plan and OneToOne relation with Garage
**(table license - columns fk_plan and fk_garage)**

The class Plan has a ManyToMany relation with MessageTemplate
**(table plan_granted_template - columns fk_plan and fk_message_template)**

The class MessageTemplate has the atribute messageType
**(table message_template - column message_type)**

This method should return all the MessageTemplate entity found on query but always returns an empty list.
Executing this query in mysql returns the correct result.
Also looking at the **Hibernate** logs, the query is executed with the correct parameters, but an empty list is returned anyway.

I think that Spring executes the query but it's fail to convert the resultSet into an MessageTemplate instance.

Comment: why you dont use JPQL instead native, do you have your entities mapped ?

Comment: Yes i have the entities mapped. I'm having dificulties with jpql, but this query executed in mysql returns the result correctly =(

Comment: Not sure if your parameters MessageTemplate messageTemplate plays weel with  template.message_type = ?1, have you tried to pass String messageTemplate, I mean conversion between the messageTemplate and String needed in the query, try to add DEBUG to see the parameters send to the database

Comment: In Hibernate logs i see the parameters converted. The garage parameter is converted the ID and messageType is converted to String.

Comment: Ok very weird problem should be with the resultSet conversion, have you tried List<Object> to see if something is coming from jpa

Comment: Hum, i will try this later to see what is coming from jpa. Thanks!

Comment: @Koitoer, you were right! I needed to pass the parameters as String and Integer. The Hibernate logs this way on both cases:
[BasicBinder:83]: binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - 1
[BasicBinder:83]: binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - WELCOME

Comment: Excellent please mark my answer as the correct, it will be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed to pass the parameters as String and Integer. The Hibernate logs this way on both cases: [BasicBinder:83]: binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - 1 [BasicBinder:83]: binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - WELCOME.

Not sure if your parameters MessageTemplate messageTemplate plays well with template.message_type = ?1, have you tried to pass String messageTemplate, I mean conversion between the messageTemplate and String needed in the query, try to add DEBUG to see the parameters send to the database

**UPDATE**
And the end parameters in the method should be string and int, not the Classes.